# What's $\lim_{x \to 0^+}\bigg(\frac{1-\cosh(x)}{x}\bigg)^x$?

Tags: calculus, limits

> Find the limit :
>   $$\lim_{x \to 0^+}\bigg(\frac{1-\cosh(x)}{x}\bigg)^x$$

I thought I'd use l'hopital's rule, but then I saw I don't have any of l'hopital's cases as this is $(\frac{0}{0})^0$ which doesn't make much sense.
I tried graphing it on desmos and symbolab and both sketched a curve that doesn't even exist in $0 < x$ but I know people who solved it and evaluated it to be $1$. 
I personally think the limit doesn't exist. What's the correct answer to this and how do I show it?

Comment: This expression is defined only if $x<0$ – or you have to consider $|1-\cos x|$.

Comment: First find the limit of the base, then decide if it's still indeterminate.

Comment: @Bernard the question was specifically as I wrote it and some people evaluated it to be equal 1 while I stated that the limit doesn't exist. I don't know, though.

Comment: [A quick WA link showing results.](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim+((1-cosh(x))%2Fx)%5Ex+as+x+approaches+0%2B). The calculation process on the "show step-by-step solution" has literally huge.

Comment: Since $\frac{1-\cosh(x)}{x}<0$ for all real $x\neq0$, you'd have difficulties defining your exponential. If you didn't understand your own question, ask what it might mean, not what is the answer.

Comment: @Rebellos I need to 'go pro' to unlock the full solution.

Comment: It's inevitably a typo and they meant $0^{-}$ or $(1-\cos x)$ or $\cosh x-1.$ (Actually, I'm guessing they just flubbed and thought their choice had the right sign.) But it does have a limit of $1$ as a complex valued function. I'm guessing the complex logarithm is outside the scope of the course though.

Comment: @EyadH. Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks!

Comment: @gimusi Yeah I forgot, sorry about that.

Comment: @EyadH. You are welcome! Bye

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**

For $x\to 0^-$ you can consider

$$\left(\frac{1-\cosh x}{x}\right)^x=e^{x{\log\frac{1-\cosh x}{x}}}$$

Comment: The question was specifically for $x \to 0^+$. Is it okay if I consider $x \to 0^-$ instead?

Comment: for $x\to0^+$ the function is not defined, maybe it is a typo on the textbook

Comment: I think the function is complex for x > 0. Why is it not defined?

Comment: @Srini I'm assuming that we are dealing with real function

Answer (score 0):

If you consider a branch of $\log$ such that negative real numbers has a logarithm, it's ok !  So
$$ \text{ for } x>0, \left(\frac{1-\cosh x}{x}\right)^x = \mathrm e^{x \log\left(\tfrac{1-\cosh x}{x}\right)} $$
Then, for $x>0$, sufficiently near of $0^+$ :
$$ \mathrm{Re}\left(\log \left(\frac{1-\cosh x}{x}\right)\right) = \ln\left(\frac{\cosh x -1}{x}\right) = \ln(x)-\ln(2)+o(1)$$
where $\ln$ denotes the natural log.
Since the imaginary part of $\log$ is bounded, we obtain that
$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}x\log\left(\frac{1-\cosh x}{x}\right) = 0 $$ 
Hence the desired limit is : $$ \lim_{x\to 0^+} \left(\frac{1-\cosh x}{x}\right)^x = 1$$